# How to prevent clicking the background?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, mobile, kineticjs

I'm a beginner trying to develop a mobile phone game with with Kinetic Js and "phonegap build". I am experiencing a problem which I don't know how to address.
I made this test: I just pasted [this code here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-events-tutorial/) into my index.html and sent the code to the [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) which created the apk file from the html code.
The apk (android installation file) can be downloaded on mobile phone following the barcode [here](http://javascriptexperiments.pbworks.com/w/page/67429240/Debugging%20touch-click).

The app works quite fine but if you play a little bit you may see an undesired behavior: the entire "stage" can be clicked with a touch and when it happens (it's actually not easy to do it on purpose, but it happens) you hear the standard click sound of the android OS and you see the entire area highlighted for a second. Just like if you were in a browser and you clicked on a link.

I tried replacing `<body>` with `<body onmousedown="return false;">` but didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: I already posted this question here before the migration, the link is this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477566/how-to-prevent-click-events-on-clickable-elements