# Removing grey box when clicking on buttons or links or anything

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 Browser - Turn off the gray shading when links are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378008/windows-phone-7-browser-turn-off-the-gray-shading-when-links-are-clicked)

When developing application for Windows Phone using phonegap, when you click on an element it gets a grey box around it. Sometimes the grey box persist for quite some time if you have huge script.

How to turn this off?

Thank you

note: 
I have tried this array of CSS without success

```
* {
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
outline: 0 none;
-moz-outline: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: This issue is already discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378008/windows-phone-7-browser-turn-off-the-gray-shading-when-links-are-clicked