# Eliminate tap highlight in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: jquery, css, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I'm building a mobile web application, and I'm having an issue with Windows Phone 7 that I'm not having on Android or iOS. The app works fairly well in Mobile IE, but since I'm using JQuery's (relatively) new .on() method, I'm getting weird tap highlighting effects that make using the app kind of annoying.

Example: I have a list of messages, like that in a twitter or email client (in the Android/iOS style), and my JS code reads as follows:

```
$('#conversation_list').on('click', '.conversation', function () {
    // show all the messages in a conversation
});
```

What ends up happening is that the *entire* top-level selector (in this case, #conversation_list) gets highlighted (and usually stays highlighted for an uncomfortable second or two). I think this could confuse some users, because there isn't the sensation that you're tapping the element you want to, even though you may be.

Is there any way to avoid this, or to just turn off tap highlighting in WinPhone IE? I'm using -webkit-tap-highlight-color successfully in iOS and Android browsers, but it doesn't seem to be working here.

Comment: What about listening to each message or each element that should highlighted?

Comment: I was under the impression that .on() required that I listen on a parent element? Is that not the case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For WP8 they added support:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
```

Source:
http://sgrebnov.blogspot.de/2012/10/windows-phone-8-for-html5js-developers.html

Answer (score 1):

See this related question:

[Windows Phone 7 Browser - Turn off the gray shading when links are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378008/windows-phone-7-browser-turn-off-the-gray-shading-when-links-are-clicked)

There is no built-in support for removing this highlight. However, a few workarounds have been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck here. tap-highlight-color is not supported in WP7. You might be able to use IE10 pressure support, but not WP7

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tap highlight in IE 10 on specific element with CSS

-ms-touch-action: none;

Comment: This removed the gray box but disallowed the overscroll in my case using windows phone 8

Answer (score 0):

As said by Lepi use:

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

in the button section in your CSS file 
&

```
$(".button").click( onTouchstart );
```

in your JS file to fire your onTouchstart() function