# Click event is not fired every time on WP7 in a Phonegap application

Tags: jquery, html, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone

We have developed an HTML5 application using JQuery (not JQuery mobile). It's working great on all the other platforms except for WP7 (7.5, 7.8). On WP7 the click events are not fired every time when an element (button, li) is tapped. When tapping an element, a gray box is displayed on top of the element but the click event is not fired.

Does anyone have similar issues and is there a solution to this?

Comment: I have the same behavior. No solution so far.

Comment: seems to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/6378008/937411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm I have experienced the same issue. First of all this is not to do with trying to hide the grey box, that is possible with a few work around as Lukas points out.

I believe this issue is a bug/limitation of PhoneGap and how it handles clicks. It seems that if you click down, move your finger a tiny fraction then release, the click event does not fire. If you do the same on the devices IE9 browser then it is much more forgiving and you can move your finger slightly during a tap and the click still fires.

I have filed this as a bug with Apache, please vote for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3565

Comment: This seems to be the case. I tested quickly with mousedown event instead of click, and it's working better.

Comment: I did similar using mouseup, works nicely unless your page scrolls and then it sometimes thinks you are clicking when you want to scroll. No ideal solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following functions for touch events in Windows:

1. MSPointerDown (for touchstart)
2. MSPointerUp (for touchend)
3. MSPointerMove (for touchmove)

Hope that helps.