# onclick overlay shadow in windows 8 app using html 5

Tags: html, css, windows-8, winjs

I am new to Windows 8 app development, I am using HTML5/CSS/JS to develop the app.

Facing an issue that for every onclick event I am getting dark shadow over the UI widgets (Button/input focus..etc)

How to avoid that dark shadow?

i am attaching the screenshot[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of this dark image?

Comment: There is a DOM explorer in Visual Studio Express, can you find the html and css for the button and paste it here?

Comment: Which CSS file are you using? 'ui-dark.css' or 'ui-light.css'?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're talking about Windows 8, right? Not Windows Phone 8. If you develop an HTML app for Windows Phone 8 you'll get that shadow on every link and I know how to fix that, but if you're actually talking about Windows 8 (or 8.1) then I agree that looking at the DOM Explorer is the best first step. If you can get a screenshot too of the visual artifact to share that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Foster , I am talking about Windows phone 8 . Could you please give me the solution ?

Comment: Thanks Maurizio In Denmark , i don't have 10 reputation to share a screen short

Comment: Thanks Jakerella ,

my html code is like :
<h1 onclick="Buttler.Anonymous.forgetDialog();">Forgot Password?</h1>

css :
 .login_container h1 {
color: #000;
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-weight: normal;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 0.7em;
}

css active: 
.login_container h1:active {
color: #FFFFFF;
}

Comment: Please refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378008/windows-phone-7-browser-turn-off-the-gray-shading-when-links-are-clicked/17670216#17670216